# Changing Text Label Color for MCA in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, factominer

I am working in rStudio to plot some MCA graphs. I have been using this code:

```
data_2 <- read.csv("https://github.com/treselle-systems/customer_churn_analysis/blob/master/WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv") 

mca.base <- MCA(as.matrix(data_2), quali.sup=19, graph=TRUE)

fviz_mca_ind(mca.base, label="var", habillage=data_2[6:14],
                  addEllipses=TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95)
```

Attached is a photo of how it looks when it's compiled.
My problem, how do I change the variable name labels to black/something readable? They are currently the exact same color as the marker and it looks terrible.

If that is not possible, is there a way that I can hide the label names and add a legend to the right?

[image]

Comment: If you could share a sample of `mca.base` to reproduce your plot using `dput(mca.base)` it would be fantastic!

Comment: `data_2 <- read.csv("https://github.com/treselle-systems/customer_churn_analysis/blob/master/WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv")
mca.base <- MCA(as.matrix(data_2), quali.sup=19, graph=TRUE)`